# what part of web.config do i insert the elmah tag?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, elmah

I want to write this

```
<elmah>
    <errorlog type="Elmah.XmlFilerErrorLog, Elmah" logPath="~/App_Data" />
</elmah>
```

or

```
<elmah>
  <errorLog type="Elmah.SQLiteErrorLog, Elmah" logPath="~/App_Data" />
</elmah>
```

however every place i tried putting this tag in i get an `Unrecognized configuration section elmah.` error. I found this question [Configuring ELMAH: Unrecognized config section error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337316/configuring-elmah-unrecognized-config-section-error) however i tried that (solution at the bottom of the question) and still get the error. Where do i put this?

-edit- i found the issue. I didnt set `<sectionGroup name="elmah">` properly. I couldnt find it online then remembered the demo had sqlite logging and i checked the demo config for clues.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to add the section group. Something like this:

```
<sectionGroup name="elmah">
  <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
</sectionGroup>
```

Then you can add the elmah section anywhere inside the "configuration" tag (not inside any other tag).

Comment: @Mattias Jakobsson - Thanks. :) Can't understand why this is not mentioned in the ELMAH site.

Comment: FYI: in the download they include an example web.config file in which this is demonstrated, could be useful if you are struggling with the configuration set-up.